# Why RxSwift Subscribe just run once in First launch viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I write a subscribe in viewWillAppear.
But it also run once in first launch app.
When I push to another viewcontroller, I use dispose().
Then I back in first viewcontroller, my subscribe func in viewWillAppear don't run.
What's wrong with my rx subscribe?

```
var listSubscribe:Disposable?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    listSubscribe = chatrooms.notifySubject.subscribe({ json in
        print("*1") //just print once in first launch
        self.loadContents()
    })
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    let controllers = tabBarController?.navigationController?.viewControllers
    if (controllers?.count)! > 1 {
        listSubscribe?.dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RxSwift documentation says ["Note that you usually do not want to manually call dispose; this is only an educational example. Calling dispose manually is usually a bad code smell."](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#disposing)

Normally, you should be doing something like this -

```swift
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        whatever.subscribe(onNext: { event in
        // do stuff
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

    }
```

As for your question, I believe you don't need to re-subscribe because you subscription will be alive and 'notifySubject' will send you updates whenever there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get some reactive implementation of `viewWillAppear` and similar functions? And forget about manual disposables handling... For example your `UIViewController` `init` will contain something like this:

```
rx.driverViewState()
    .asObservable()
    .filter({ $0 == .willAppear })
    .take(1) // if you need only first viewWillAppear call
    .flatMapLatest({ _ in
        // Do what you need
    })
```

And the implementation of `driverViewState`:

```
public extension UIViewController {

    public enum ViewState {
        case unknown, didAppear, didDisappear, willAppear, willDisappear
    }
}

public extension Reactive where Base: UIViewController {

    private typealias _StateSelector = (Selector, UIViewController.ViewState)
    private typealias _State = UIViewController.ViewState

    private func observableAppearance(_ selector: Selector, state: _State) -> Observable<UIViewController.ViewState> {
        return (base as UIViewController).rx
            .methodInvoked(selector)
            .map { _ in state }
    }

    func driverViewState() -> Driver<UIViewController.ViewState> {
        let statesAndSelectors: [_StateSelector] = [
            (#selector(UIViewController.viewDidAppear(_:)), .didAppear),
            (#selector(UIViewController.viewDidDisappear(_:)), .didDisappear),
            (#selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:)), .willAppear),
            (#selector(UIViewController.viewWillDisappear(_:)), .willDisappear)
        ]
        let observables = statesAndSelectors
            .map({ observableAppearance($0.0, state: $0.1) })
        return Observable
            .from(observables)
            .merge()
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: UIViewController.ViewState.unknown)
            .startWith(UIViewController.ViewState.unknown)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
    }
}
```